# Alert function not working in Body tag

Tags: javascript, html, alert, document-body

```
<body onload="alert("Hello World")">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

why doesn't this work?

EDIT
Additionally, why does chrome dev tools report "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " that as the error message?

Thanks,
funbeans

Comment: Next time when something doesn't work, before wondering why, press F12.

Comment: Actually, interesting point, and I wish I would've put this in the question. Chrome just keeps saying there was an unexpected character "{" and I kept looking for a curly brace, but there were none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<body onload="alert('Hello World')">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

The issue is with nested quotes

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dkC92/)

Comment: It happens. One recommendation though: Do see the browser's console  to see if it catches any syntax errors.

Comment: In this case the browser;s console shows an error - something like: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: why "}" ? I guess the reg exp the interpreter is looking for expects a {, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: That is the way Javascript has been parsed. The parser is expecting end of a block, but found something else instead

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with double quotes, you need to escape them:

```
<body onload="alert(\"Hello World\")">
```

Or use single quotes:

```
<body onload="alert('Hello World')">
```

This happens because when you use double quote HTML think that your attribute is ended and contains of only `alert(` and the rest `"Hello World")"` is another attribute.